# promise .then() to run sequentially inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to fill my `$scope.results = []` sequentially by multiple sequential API calls. sequential is important as i'm passing in a start and a limit number (something like pagination). There is a reason that I cannot do this in 1 call and need to break into multiple calls since the API gateway timeouts after  30s.

My problem is in the for loop it doesnt work sequentially. Inside the array all network requests seem to get the same `start` values and are not sent sequentially. I also cannot use `async/await`. Is there a way to run the API calls sequentially and get add the result to the `results` array. My final goal is to fill the array like it happened in a single API call but with multiple calls

```
         $scope.detailedReportOfAll = function () {
            $scope.start = 0;
            $scope.limit = 15;
            $scope.results = [];
            var requestCount = 1;
            APIService.getDetailedReportData($scope.start,$scope.limit).then(
              function ({result,nbPages}) {
                if (result.length){
                  $scope.results = $scope.results.concat(result);
                  requestCount ++;
                  $scope.start += $scope.limit;
                }
                if (requestCount < nbPages){ //I'm running the loop for (nbPages - 1) times

                  for (i=2; i<nbPages; i++){
                    APIService.getDetailedReportData($scope.start,$scope.limit).then(
                      function ({result,nbPages}) {
                        if (result.length){
                          $scope.results = $scope.results.concat(result);
                          requestCount ++;
                          console.log($scope.results, requestCount)
                          $scope.start += $scope.limit;
                        }
                      })
                  }
                }
              }
            );
          };
```

this is my http calling function. it returns a promise

```js
    var getDetailedReportData= function (start, limit) {
      $rootScope.isLoading = true;
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http
        .get(rootURL('/getAllReports/'+start+'/'+limit))
        .success(function (response) {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        })
        .finally(function () {
          $rootScope.isLoading = false;
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Use `async` and `await` instead of `.then()` if you want to sequence asynchronous operations in a `for` loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 For some reason no async awaits are used in the codebase. Probably to support old browsers?

Comment: Well you should find out the "for some reason" because modern technology is the simplest, easiest way to solve this problem.  Manually sequenced asynchronous loops can be written, but they are not as simple as `async/await`.

Comment: This is **much** easier with `async`/`await` so if, for some reasons you need to support browsers which don't support that, I would use `async`/`await` anyway and then transpile them out with Babel.

Comment: Do you have to run the requests sequentially (2nd one doesn't start until first one finishes) or do you just need the results collated into the right sequence?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I need the results array in sequence. Initially I returned the results in 1 api call without start/limit. But had to change because when dataset is large query becomes large, before query finishes API gateway timeouts

Comment: @jfriend00 Suppose if I have to perform 4 network calls in sequence and if 2nd network call is a POST method and if 3rd network call fails due to some reason. Then already I have some data committed as a part of 3rd network call (through POST method) and the operation is not sucessful as 3rd network call is broken. How to handle this scenario as I have already committed some data as part of 3rd network call?

Comment: @anupr - Since this is not your question and you're asking something different, please write your own question that describes your exact situation and shows your actual code.  If you want, you can link to it here in a comment addressed to me and I'll take a look when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run these in series then you need to trigger async function *n* when you know that async function *n-1* is finished; i.e. in the `then` callback. Calling a function recursively is likely to be the easiest way to do this if you've rejected `async` and `await`.

```js
function somethingAsync(value) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500, value * value));
}

function processInputInSeries(input) {
    function processNext(index, input, results) {
        if (index >= input.length) return results;
        return somethingAsync(input[index]).then(function (result) {
            return processNext(index + 1, input, [...results, result]);
        });
    }

    return processNext(0, input, []);
}

const resultPromise = processInputInSeries([1,2,3]);
resultPromise.then(function(results) { console.log(results) });
```

For comparison, `async`/`await` is much clearer:

```js
function somethingAsync(value) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500, value * value));
}

async function processInputInSeries(input) {
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        const result = await somethingAsync(input[i]);
        results = [...results, result];
    }
    return results;
}

const resultPromise = processInputInSeries([1,2,3]);
resultPromise.then(function(results) { console.log(results) });
```

I would recommend writing it that way even if you end up using Babel to transpile your JS to be compatible with outdated systems.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried with the recursive solution and got it working.